# Libgdx Camera for Group Only

Tags: java, libgdx

I am trying to move my boxes inside a group by camera. Users are able to move(right, left, top, bottom) and zoom inside the group. But when i implement camera to stage, it will zoom out/in all elements as expected. Is there a way to implement a camera just for group.

I do not want to change my group position and size(green rectangle below), just changes boxes inside the group. Is there any example how to implement this?

This is my camera create code for stage( i could not find any example to attach camera to group)

```
 camera = new OrthographicCamera();
    stage = new Stage(new ScalingViewport(Scaling.stretch, iosSafeAreaInsets.x, iosSafeAreaInsets.y, camera), batch);
```

[image: Initial image]

[image: Zoomed out image]

Comment: Are you saying you want to zoom or scale the contents of this group without modifying the group's outer border or anything else in the stage?

Comment: Yes that is what i want to do exactly